# Selecting from SDO_ELEM_INFO in Oracle geometry

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to convert geometry from SDO_GEOM to WKT via `SDO_UTIL.WKTGEOMETRY()` function. But table has compound geometries which are not able to convert to WKT. I need to skip these geometries. In SDO_ETYPE which is in SDO_ELEM_INFO the compound geometry has id 1005 or 2005.

Is there any way how to get value from SDO_ETYPE and use it in WHERE condition? Something like:

```
select SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY(g.sdo_geom) from geometry_table g WHERE g.sdo_geom.SDO_ELEM_INFO.SDO_ETYPE NOT IN (1005, 2005);
```

I am able to get `g.sdo_geom.SDO_ELEM_INFO` but when I tried `g.sdo_geom.SDO_ELEM_INFO.SDO_ETYPE` there was an error, because there is not a such attribute. I also tried to find some function which extract value from ELEM_INFO_ARRAY but I had no luck.

I am using cx_Oracle so it would be much easier use this in select then extract values via cx_Oracle and then convert geometry again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, try it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM geometry_table WHERE ID IN
      (SELECT DISTINCT ID
       FROM
        (SELECT ID,
          TRUNC((ROWNUM - 1) / 3, 0) elem_num,
          MAX(DECODE(MOD(ROWNUM, 3), 1, t.COLUMN_VALUE, NULL)) offset,
          MAX(DECODE(MOD(ROWNUM, 3), 2, t.COLUMN_VALUE, NULL)) etype,
          MAX(DECODE(MOD(ROWNUM, 3), 0, t.COLUMN_VALUE, NULL)) interpretation
         FROM geometry_table g,
          TABLE(g.SDO_GEOM.sdo_elem_info) t
        GROUP BY TRUNC((ROWNUM - 1) / 3, 0), ID
        )
      WHERE etype IN (1005,2005)
      );
```